# Modifying R package maintained by someone else

Tags: r, cran

There's a semantic error in a function of an R package written by someone else.  I contacted that person which is mentioned in the 'DESCRIPTION' file of the package over email, and there is no response. But, I need to move forward with my project.

Is it possible for me to correct that error and check-in the change of that project ? If that's not possible, should I write my own version of the function with the correction and call it? What would be the best way to move forward ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to update that particular package on CRAN is to contact the package maintainer. But you can just obtain the package's sources (you can fork it from [CRAN readonly mirror](https://github.com/cran/) on a github), fix it your way and source changed .R files after loading the package (or build entire package from sources if your fixes are in C++ code). I've done it many times. If your changes may be useful to the community, you're encouraged to create your own package.

Comment: The thing I'd add is, if this is a package where the source is on github, you would do the world a favor by forking the project and uploading your change with an explanation.  Perhaps the maintainer will show up one day, or perhaps in some months other users of the package will use your git to implement other fixes and your variant will then replace the unmaintained one.

Comment: There's already a fork by another person which is waiting for commit for the past 10 months! 

The funny thing is the author is well connected in social networking. I am going to get in touch with them through LinkedIn, Skype, or whatever way possible :).